# SQL Ntext Items Only Having the First Two Chars Read in

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am currently programming a C# program that lets students log into an interface, check grades, etc.. Admins can create new users. The student IDs are 9-digit codes that all begin with "95." When an admin is creating a new user, I want to go through the database to make sure that the ID number they have entered isn't already taken.

To do this, I have the following code:

```
connection.Open();
readerUsers = commandUsers.ExecuteReader();

while (readerUsers.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(readerUsers[2].ToString());

    if(readerUsers[2].ToString() == IDNum)
    {
        userAlreadyExists = true;
        break;
    }
}

connection.Close();
```

And in my Users table, which `readerUsers` and `commandUsers` are connected to, I have the following:

```
IDuser     Username    95Number    Password   Active   Admin
-------------------------------------------------------------
  1          sward     951619984     uo99lb    True     True
 ...          ...         ...         ...      ...      ...
```

Now, when I went to test my code by creating a user with the ID number of 951619984 (a number already entered in the database), `userAlreadyExists` would still remain false. So I made the program show a message box of each item in the 95Number column (which is of type `Ntext`). Every time, the message box would only show "95".

I am very new to programming with databases, so I apologize if this is a very newby question, but I'm not sure what to do to get the whole string from this `ntext` column. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Comment: `ntext` is deprecated and will be removed. Use `nvarchar(max)` instead.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql

Comment: Please add the SQL query used by the reader.

Comment: This first and probably biggest issue is that you are using the ntext datatype. It has been deprecated for more than 15 years now in favor of nvarchar(max). But to be honest you don't need to use a max datatype here. You are not storing anywhere near that much information.

Comment: Passwords should always be hashed and not stored as plain text.

Comment: You also should not be pulling down the entire table and using C# to iterate every row.

Comment: I have changed the ntext types to nvarchar(max), but my problem still remains. (Thanks for the info about the nvarchar datatype though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way of doing that:

```
var connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["your key"].ConnectionString;
var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE [95number]=@num";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add("num",SqlDbType.Int).Value = IDNum;
  conn.Open();
  var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  userAlreadyExists = result > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did mines this way.

```
string Qstring = "Select 95number where 95number = '95#########'";

 using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(Form1.ConnectionStringGen))
            using (SqlCommand Com = con.CreateCommand())
            {


                Com.CommandText = Qstring;
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader Reader = Com.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if(Reader.Read())
                    {
                       string 95Numb = Reader["95Number"].ToString();
                       Messagebox.show(95Numb);

                       userAlreadyExists = true;

                       //meaning if the reader reads an item it will prompt 

                    }
                    else
                    {

                     userAlreadyExists = false;

                   }
                }
                con.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```